# How do I add seasonal & trend components to the final prediction when using neural networks?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, seasonality, trend

I've got a question about stationarity: let's say I've made seasonal & trend adjustment for my time series input, scaled it and then passed this data to some NN model (e.g., LSTM or windowed-MLP), how do I add seasonal & trend components to the final answer?

Comment: This comment raises a rhetorical question. The authors of the paper *Statistical and Machine Learning forecasting methods: Concerns and ways forward* found that machine learning time series models, at a minimum, did not improve predictions over statistical models and in many cases were less computationally efficient (http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0194889&type=printable) Given these fairly conclusive findings, does it make sense to proceed with a NN model of time series *at all* when statistical models are so much more tractable, efficient, etc.?

Comment: Well, I've found a lot of articles on arxiv.org that say NN models performs better than ARIMA-like methods. The issue is that I cannot integrate ARIMA into my Go code, and I can easily do it with NN model (just hardcode the weight of the model).

Comment: @AlexKornakov can you link to some of those articles?

Comment: @Alex, well, one of the first articles I was able to google: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258221036_Comparison_between_ARIMA_Models_and_Artificial_Neural_Networks_in_Forecasting_Al-Quds_indices_of_Palestine_Stock_Exchange_Market

Comment: @DJohnson anyway, what's the best way (aside from ARIMA and LR) to forecast time series than?

One more article: https://eng.uber.com/neural-networks/

Comment: Thank you for the links. The Uber paper was the more interesting of the two. I found several pretty blatant mistakes in their analysis the most important of which is that they used only a small subset of data -- significantly less than one full year -- to train their models (figs. 1-3, 7). Any experienced time series statistician knows that to initialize seasonal events such as Xmas you need at least two full years of data. Next, NNs require the levels of categorical features be transformed into 0,1 dummy variables, i.e., NNs are unable to treat categorical features as categorical. ctd.>>

Comment: Finally, sampling and treating observations (records, the smallest unit of data) as *iid* ignores inherent structure and variance, e.g., cross-sections such as *city* or seasonalities due to time of day, day, week, month, etc., get lost. My view is that their approach is destructive of explanatory information, structure and variance. A much better approach to modeling time series and especially exceedances or extreme events would be quantile regression rooted in panel data techniques.

Comment: @AlexKornakov I don't have time to write a full answer now. I will later. To answer your comment about other approaches besides ARIMA and LR, exponential smoothing is one the most commonly used methods and in many cases has been shown to perform better than more complex methods.

Comment: @Alex, thank you in advance, it sounds extremely promising!

Comment: BTW, I've got 35 RMSE when using linear regression and less than 1 (yes!) when using LSTM from this tutorial (https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/#comment-438949): https://imgur.com/a/RvDo2wu. Probably it's about overfitting, but still 35 -> even 10 looks pretty solid, IMO (this's a plot from a simpler LSTM model: https://imgur.com/a/FDsQgNo).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8Y7Gmpo

Comment: @DJohnson here's what I get by using LSTM model: https://imgur.com/a/wq5Ha3O The 1st array is the real data, I used log = 3, so I don't predict the 1st 3 values and then you can see the quality of forecast is superb (03:00:00 -> real value: 468, forecasted: 491, 04:00:00 -> real: 681, forecasted: 667). Will try to use exponential smoothing right now!

Comment: @DJohnson the forecast in the graph from the last comment is too good to be true. Are you sure you're not overfitting the data? Or another common mistake I have seen when people use LSTM is that it seems like the LSTM is doing a very good job of estimating the shape pdf the signal when in fact is simply performing a naive 1-step ahead forecast (i.e. it simply memorized the input signal). Have you tried it for n-septs ahead? Also based on your actual values you might want to look into using the TBATS approach, since you have multiple seasonalities in the same series.

Comment: I thought about overfitting, too, and then I run this model on a completely different data and got that plot. I used this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/). Actually it's 4300-steps ahead (for about half a year and I pasted a plot for a random month here). TBATS is a good idea, but I want to be able to insert my model into Java code.

Comment: And exponential smoothing behaves strangely for my data: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348803/strange-output-while-using-holt-s-linear-trend-method I can send you a code & data if you don't believe that LSTM is so good.

Comment: @AlexKornakov for exponential smoothing, you are using Holt's linear (also called double exponential smoothing) when in fact you should be using Holt-Winters (triple exponential smoothing).

Comment: @AlexKornakov also can you please clarify which method you used to deseasobalise and detrend your data?

Comment: @Alex do you mean for LSTM or Holt-Winters method? LSTM: use lag = 3, didn't use anything to deseasobalise and detrend my data for Holt-Winters method (just copy pasted code from that tutorial).

Comment: If someone is looking at this topic -> nice way of joining ES and NN methods posted by Slawek Smyl who won last m4 forecasting competition
https://github.com/M4Competition/M4-methods/blob/slaweks_ES-RNN/ES_RNN_SlawekSmyl.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the main question:

> how do I add seasonal & trend components to the final answer?

First you need to be careful with the terminology. Making a series stationary and removing trend and seasonality from a series are not the same thing - even though they are related.

More specifically - removing trend and seasonality might make a series stationary, but there is also the possibility that even after removing the trend and the seasonality, the series is still not stationary (for the variance is still no constant even after detrending and deseasonalising).

Bringing back the seasonality and the trend into the forecast after removing them also depends on what transformation you used to detrend and deseasonalize the signal in the first place.

If differencing was used to make the series stationary (the way it usually is in ARIMA models) then cumulative summing is how you reverse transform the data back to it's original shape. Note that when differencing is used, then the trend and seasonality are being removed implicitly not explicitly.

For example if your differencing order is one:

Original series:

$X_1,X_2,X_3...X_n$

Differenced series:

$Y_1 = X_1$

and for $n>1$

$Y_n = X_{n+1} - X_n$

Initial forecast series:

$\hat{Y}_1,\hat{Y}_2,....\hat{Y}_n$

Final (summed) forecast series:

$\hat{X}_1 = \hat{Y}_1$

For $n>1$

$\hat{X}_n = \hat{Y}_1+\hat{Y}_2+...+\hat{Y}_n$

Other approaches such as Facebook Prophet (GAM based) or STL() try to model the trend $T$, the seasonal component $S$ and the residuals $R$ individually and then add them back together.

In such cases, you try to explicitly model the trend $\hat{T}$, the seasonality $\hat{S}$, and the residuals $\hat{R}$ and then you simply add them back together:

$\hat{X}_n = \hat{T}_n +\hat{S}_n+\hat{R}_n$.

---

*A note on the use of Neural Networks based on the discussion in the comments on the OP (Full disclosure: I am more of a practitioner of time series - I do demand forecasting for retail - than an academic).*

From what I see, the idea of Neural Networks - especially LSTM - outperforming traditional methods like ARIMA and exponential smoothing seems to driven mainly by the current overall hype for using Neural Networks and Tensorflow to try to solve every single data science problem out there. Google (and Amazon with their DeepAR model) have been pushing for this since it brings more customers to their cloud platform.

The results in the academic literature seem to be more nuanced and mixed.

In theory, for an LSTM to perform better than Triple Exponential Smoothing, Seasonal ARIMA or TBATS, means that your time series has to have highly complex non linear patterns beyond the seasonal and trend components. In practice, I've found such time series to be rare, and anything that can be modeled by an LSTM can also be modeled by a simpler statistical model with considerably less computational cost and the additional benefit of being easier to interpret.