# Strange output while using Holt’s Linear Trend method

Tags: time-series, exponential-smoothing, pandas

Here're the pictures of using Holt’s Linear Trend method:

*From tutorial (what it should be like)*:
[image]
*After running the code for my data*
[image]

Isn't it strange?

Here's a [code (method #5)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/02/time-series-forecasting-methods/):

```
y_hat_avg = df_test.copy()

fit1 = Holt(np.asarray(df_train['pickups'])).fit(smoothing_level = 0.3,smoothing_slope = 0.1)
y_hat_avg['Holt_linear'] = fit1.forecast(len(df_test))

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot(df_train['pickups'], label='Train')
plt.plot(df_test['pickups'], label='Test')
plt.plot(y_hat_avg['Holt_linear'], label='Holt_linear')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(test.pickups, y_hat_avg.Holt_linear))
print(rmse)
```

After I run `y_hat_avg.Holt_linear.tail()` I didn't get any NaNs:

```
2014-08-31 19:00:00    603.553557
2014-08-31 20:00:00    604.220995
2014-08-31 21:00:00    604.888432
2014-08-31 22:00:00    605.555870
2014-08-31 23:00:00    606.223308
Name: Holt_linear, dtype: float64
```

UPD: when using `fit1 = ExponentialSmoothing(np.asarray(df_train['pickups']) ,seasonal_periods=7 ,trend='add', seasonal='add',).fit()` I receive a similar result.

Comment: From the page you linked too, you should be using method #6, not #5.

Comment: @Alex, I receive similar strange picture for both #5 and #6 methods.